# Effectively dealing with x quantity $_POST vars

Tags: php

I have a piece of code that I'm not happy with at all:

```
// Search for checkboxes ('chk-1','chk-2','chk-3'...)
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if (substr($key, 0,3) == 'chk') {  
        $appObj->cats[] = intval(substr($key,4,strlen($key)));
}
```

I really don't like this as $_POST can contain upwards of 40+ variables and I am already applying logic to all other posted vars.

Has anyone got any ideas / solutions to achieving the above without cycling through every $_POST var?

Comment: You could use an array instead of numbers attached to the basename, see [Example #3 More complex form variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#example-106)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way how you could avoid cycling trough all items and using `strncmp`, `strpos` or `substr` is building check-boxes as one array (lets have `$key = 7` as example):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[7]" />
```

And php:

```
foreach( $_POST['chk'] as $key => $val){
    $appObj->cats[] = $key;
}
```

This would would, but it may create key gaping:

```
$_POST['chk'] = array(
  0 => 'ON',
  1 => 'ON',
  7 => 'ON',
);
```

Which may cause problems when someone will try processing data with `for` loop.

Better approach is this one:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="7" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="57" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="1231" />
```

And php:

```
foreach( $_POST['chk'] as $arrayKey => $key){
    $appObj->cats[] = $key;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer Vyktor, I hadn't considered passing an array to the HTML tags name value. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use name="chk[]" in form control.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="1"> 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="2"> 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="3"> 3<br />
```

And then check if you have an array.

```
if( !empty($_POST["chk"]) )
{
    print_r($_POST["chk"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Running a `foreach` through `$_POST` is really not a crime and is probably the only way to do this.

If you are already appyling other logic why not put this all in the same `foreach`?

Also to save you some processing you don't need to pass `strlen($key)` as the 3rd paramater in `substr` just exclude that parameter completely and it will do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer fire, the other answers here better respond to my question though appreciate the comment on `substr`. +1 for showing me something I didn't know I could do.